# Pass data from child to child in Vue

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, token, registration

So.. in my application, at the `Authentication` chapter, i have some questions.

First of all i have multiple components/routes, two of them being `register` and `login`.

`Register` works fine, using my api, in respond i get an `username` and `account_id`, both being stored in database.

When trying to `log in`, in respond i get `username` and `token`.. Now, when i access other routes in my website that can only be accesed if you're logged in, i need to detect if a token is present. How can i make like a global variable that has `token` value and it can be accesed easily by other components ?

Comment: Hello. This question is a too broad for the StackOverflow standards where usually a very specific problem with a code example is present.How it's handled depends on your setup - are you using Vue Router or VueX? etc. At a high level, you will need to store your token either in a Vuex Store if you have one or as a global variable. Then you have to use [Vue router navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to check for a valid token before every route transition. You may also need to pass your token along with any further API requests you may need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your token in cookie / localstorage and if you are using vuex you can store it in the state also.

If you are using Axios or any other tool for ajax requests, you can pass your token in headers and just pick it up from either cookie / localstorage.

```
state: {
   token: Cookie.getJSON('token') || null,
},
mutations: {
  setToken: (state, data) => {
    state.token = data
    Cookie.set('token', data)
  }
},
actions: {
  setToken (context, data) {
    context.commit('setToken', data.token)
  }
}
```

Check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie

Comment: But which one is better to use ? Cookies or Vuex overall ? What's the main difference ? Cookies are pretty easy to use, so what's not enough ? Same for Vuex .. ?

Comment: I use cookies (in case the user does a page refresh) and also use vuex store (to use it in my SPA).
I am putting the code in the answer above.

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty easy and useful. Thank you for your response. But wanna make sure.. : Your code is fine right ? I mean this way of combining both of them provides good stability, i shouldn't encounter problems on my way of developing the website yea ?

Comment: I am working on a website - coversingers.com and i have used the same code. Just make sure when you log out the user, unset the state and delete the cookies.